# Edit Web.Config - "System.Net" Section Programmatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, edit, system.net

I want to change the "system.net" section in web.config. I want to add or remove defaultProxy tag according to a variable in runtime.

```
<defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="false">
  <module type = "XXX.Utils.YYProxy, XXX" />
</defaultProxy>
```

I know, there are related posts editing web.config, but they all related with `ConnectionStringsSection` or `AppSettingsSection`. There are specific classes about them in System.Configuration package, but I did not find any class related with "system.net".

Do you know any quick way to handle this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do this. I enable or disable the defaultProxy tag with following code:

```
Configuration config = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
NetSectionGroup netSection = (NetSectionGroup)config.GetSectionGroup("system.net");
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.ProxyUrl))
    netSection.DefaultProxy.Enabled = false;
else
    netSection.DefaultProxy.Enabled = true;
```

The key point was casting the **SectionGroup** to **NetSectionGroup** class.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing the defaultProxy element from web.config, I recommend that, in your code, you override the proxy that is used based on the value assigned to the variable to which you refer.

For example:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://stackoverflow.com/");

if(variable == "some expected value to override default proxy") {
    //by setting the Proxy property of the Request object to a new WebProxy class, you override the default
    request.Proxy = new WebProxy("http://someproxyserver.com:80", true);
}
```

Of course, I'd need to see more of your code to give a more complete answer.

Hope this helps!